# Unable to upload image into root folder using PHP

Tags: php, html, image, file-upload, upload

Following is code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $file=$_FILES['file'];
  $fileName=$_FILES['file']['name'];
  $fileTmpName=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  $fileSize=$_FILES['file']['size'];
  $fileError=$_FILES['file']['error'];
  $fileType=$_FILES['file']['type'];
  $fileExt=explode('.',$filename);
  $fileActualExt=strtolower(end($fileExt));
  $allowed=array('jpg','jpeg','png','pdf');
  if(in_array($fileActualExt,$allowed)){
    if($fileError===0)
    {
      if($fileSize<1000000){
        $fileNameNew=uniqid('',true).".".$fileActualExt;
        $fileDestination='uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
        move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$fileDestination);
        header("Location:index.php?uploadsucess");
      }
      else{
        echo "File is too big";
      }
    }
    else{
      echo "there was an error in uploading";
    }
  }
  else
  {
    echo "You cannot upload a file of this type";
  }
}
?>
```

And it shows following errors:

> Error
>
> Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\fileupload\upload.php
>   on line 3
>
> Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\fileupload\upload.php
>   on line 4
>
> Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\fileupload\upload.php
>   on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\fileupload\upload.php
>   on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\fileupload\upload.php
>   on line 7
>
> Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\fileupload\upload.php
>   on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: filename in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\fileupload\upload.php on line 10
>
> You cannot upload file of this type

Comment: show your html code

Comment: Show your form HTML also.

Comment: Don't you forget to add something like `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as an attribute in your HTML `<form>` ?

Comment: i added Even though I am getting an error.

Comment: <?php
session_start(); 
mysql_select_db('formdata',mysql_connect('localhost','root','mysql'))or die(mysql_error());
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>File Uploading</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>Select Your Image</h1>
</br>
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/for-data">
<input type="file" name="file">
</br></br>
<button type="submit" name="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>

Comment: check your input type should be like this as per your code
 `<input type="file" name="file">` and must have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: `enctype="multipart/for-data"` => `enctype="multipart/form-data"` a letter could be iportant ;)

Comment: Thank and now a Small error Notice: Undefined variable: filename in C:\xampp\htdocs\fileupload\upload.php on line 10

Comment: Problem Solved.Love You guysThank You all for responding

Comment: Please consider formatting your code for better readability and try to explain it a bit next time you open a question.

Comment: Place the solution as an answer instead of keeping it all in the comments.

Comment: definite i will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you forget to add something like `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as an attribute in your HTML `<form>` ?